# Replace numbers in brackets with a link - php regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to place product links in a description.

```
$myDesc="this is some text about the thing on the page and it 
has a match <a href="[1145]">this product</a> 
also has another matching <a href="[101145]">product</a>.";
```

would like to replace the product numbers '$theNumber' with a function that will retrieve the correct link... something like this

```
$myDesc = preg_replace("/\\[([0-9]+)\\]/", productlink('$1'), $myDesc);
```

The end result will be similar tho this

```
this is some text about the thing on the page and it 
has a match <a href="http://www.example.com/this-product-name-1145">this product</a> 
also has another matching <a href="http://www.example.com/another-product-name-101145">product</a>.
```

Thanks for any insight

Comment: 1. https://google.com 2. `PHP preg_replace() function inside` | 1. https://php.net 2. top right: `preg_replace_`

Comment: seems `[1145]` needs to be replaced with link generated by `productlink($theNumber)`, whereas `[101145]` will also be replaced or remain same ?

Comment: @kamalpal I think replace means replace :)

Comment: This is unclear to me what you want to do. What does `productlink($theNumber)` do?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes, actually I thought `[1145]` this one is product ID, and `[101145]` is similar product as per description. so bit confused that the same link needs to be replaced for both. :)

Comment: Is your question why `preg_replace(/\[[^0-9\]]*\]/` doesn't work or something to do with the function `productlink(`?

Comment: productlink($theNumber) is a function that gets the correct link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you.

Syntax issue:

Double quotes need to be escaped when there are used inside a string encapsulated by double quotes.

Regex issue:

Your regex said...find a literal `[` then any non-numbers or a bracket zero or more times, `\[[^0-9\]]*\]`. You instead want a bracket, any numbers, one or more times, followed by a bracket, `\[([0-9]+)\]`. You didn't provide the function `productlink` so I don't know what that does, here's my best guess.

You also needed your regex to be in quotes, `'~\[([0-9]+)\]~'`.

```
<?php
$myDesc = 'this is some text about the thing on the page and it 
has a match <a href="[1145]">this product</a> 
also has another matching <a href="[101145]">product</a>.';
$myDesc = preg_replace_callback('~\[([0-9]+)\]~', "productlink", $myDesc);
echo $myDesc;
function productlink($theNumber) {
    //select title from DB
    //$title =  fetched title
    $title = '';
    $title = str_replace(' ', '-', $title) . '-';
    return 'http://www.example.com/' . $title . $theNumber[1];
}
```

Output:

```
this is some text about the thing on the page and it 
has a match <a href="http://www.example.com/-1145">this product</a> 
also has another matching <a href="http://www.example.com/-101145">product</a>.
```